# Boolean matrix lines/columns swapping to match target

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, linear-transformations

Consider "A" and "B", both N $\times$ N symmetric boolean matrices ($0/1$ elements).
B was obtained from A, by randomly swapping lines, with one constraint: when rows ($i$) and ($j$) get swapped, columns ($i$) and ($j$) will be swapped next.
An indefinite number of such operations are made. 
Is there any way that starting from B, I can identify the ($i, j$) lines (followed by columns) pairs to swap back so that I reach A again? Thanks!

PS. You can consider A and B as the adjacency matrices of an undirected graph before and after nodes are interchanged.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to finding an isomorphism between two graphs? Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639003/is-there-any-algorithm-to-find-isomorphism-function-between-two-graphs

Comment: I am a newbie in this area, but reading a bit about it seems to be my case. I know the graphs are isomorphic, but I need to indicate the node swaps that transformed one into another. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Look at the question I linked to. I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any algorithm to find Isomorphism function between two graphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639003/is-there-any-algorithm-to-find-isomorphism-function-between-two-graphs)